# Setting maximum string length in ExtractingRequestHandler ("Solr Cell") .. setMaxStringLength()

Tags: solr, solr-cell

I'm using Solr and ExtractingRequestHandler to index documents but I do not know how to do the equivalent of Tika setMaxStringLength().

It appears to be indexing all of the smaller documents but not all of the text of a large document, which might imply that it's not setting tika.setMaxStringLength(-1)

Is it possible to set the value in solrconfig.xml?
Is it possible to pass the value along with other parameters when posting using curl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Solr Config file for the limit

```
<maxFieldLength>10000</maxFieldLength>
```

This would limit the field length, which might be causing issues for you.

Which version of solr are you using, as it might have been deprecated.

[IndexConfig in SolrConfig](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/IndexConfig+in+SolrConfig)

> The maxFieldLength parameter was removed in Solr 4. If restricting the
>   length of fields is important to you, you can get similar behavior
>   with the LimitTokenCountFactory, which can be defined for the fields
>   you'd like to limit. For example, 
>   would limit the field to 10,000 characters.

Comment: Thank you. maxFieldLength was indeed the culprit in my case, as you suggested. I am still using Solr 3.x and moving to Solr 4 soon.